# Reformat weird Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

| Name | place | pers_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | Nan |
| Smith John | NY | sjohn@gmail.com |
| NaN | Nan | 0987 4567 |
| NaN | NaN | 0653 6734 |
| Vic Stied | SA | 0986 5332 |
| NaN | NaN | vickie@hotmail.com |

I would like to delete the NaN values and reformat the file like the following :

| Name | Place | pers_data | other | other_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith John | NY | sjohn@gmail.com | 0987 4567 | 0653 6734 |
| Vic Stied | SA | vickie@hotmail.com | 0986 5332 |  |

Can someone help me with that, I tried some stuff but without understanding anything, I'd like to really get what I am doing.

Comment: Could you please change the title of the question to something specific?

Answer (score 4):

This is a variation on a `pivot`:

```
idx = df['Name'].notna().cumsum()
out = (df
   .assign(col=df.groupby(idx).cumcount(),
           Name=df['Name'].groupby(idx).ffill(),
           place=df['place'].groupby(idx).ffill()
          )
   .pivot(index=['Name', 'place'], columns='col', values='pers_data')
   .add_prefix('other_').rename(columns={'other_0': 'pers_data'})
   .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
   .dropna(how='all')
)
```

output:

```
         Name place        pers_data             other_1    other_2
1  Smith John    NY  sjohn@gmail.com           0987 4567  0653 6734
2   Vic Stied    SA        0986 5332  vickie@hotmail.com        NaN
```

Comment: There seems to be something off in the second row of the output. The pers_date and other_1 are flipped.

Comment: They are provided as they are found in the input data

Comment: @Christian well, there are in original order. Without OP explaining specific rules, there is no direct way pandas can discriminate between an email address and a phone number.

Comment: True story. Please ignore my comment :)

Comment: @Christian this is still a valid comment, and doable, but you would need to write some rules to identify the different types of data and decide how to organize them (for instance, if there was no email, should the `pers_data` column remain empty?). Probably worth a follow-up question if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have this error while trying on a bigger dataset "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape", do you have any idea where this come from

Comment: Do you have duplicated names?

Comment: Nope, I have df['Name'] as index and the error is now saying that it can't find 'Name', because it is an index I guess. If I don't have df['Name'] as index I got the following error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Comment: In order to debug, please provide the example input DataFrame of the question as a `DataFrame` constructor.

Comment: Alright I am going to do that but this is confidential informations so I need to change values

Comment: Actually, when I am trying with the example I gave, it is not working either. I don'"t know what you mean by Dataframe constructor, I am knew

Comment: Just provide the DataFrame constructor for explicitness (= code to produce a valid object: `df = pd.DataFrame(...)`). It's currently not possible to say if we're working with the same data.

Comment: test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['NaN','Smith John','NaN','NaN','Vic Stied','NaN'],
    'place':['NaN','NY','NaN','NaN','SA','NaN'],
    'pers_data':['NaN','sjohn@gmail.com','0987 4567','0653 6734','0986 5332','vickie@hotmail.com']
})

Comment: It's because you don't have real NaN but strings. Use `test_df = test_df.replace('NaN', pd.NA)` as initial step.

Comment: I change to pd.NA but I still have the same errors as before

Comment: Works for me on the provided `test_df`… (using `df` as a name though)

Comment: Here is my code :
`df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name':['NaN','Smith John','NaN','NaN','Vic Stied','NaN'],
    'place':['NaN','NY','NaN','NaN','SA','NaN'],
    'pers_data':['NaN','sjohn@gmail.com','0987 4567','0653 6734','0986 5332','vickie@hotmail.com']
})
df.replace('NaN',pd.NA)`

Comment: `idx = df['Name'].notna().cumsum()
out = (df
   .assign(col=df.groupby(idx).cumcount(),
           Name=df['Name'].groupby(idx).ffill(),
           place=df['place'].groupby(idx).ffill()
          )
   .pivot(index=['Name', 'place'], columns='col', values='pers_data')
   .add_prefix('other_').rename(columns={'other_0': 'pers_data'})
   .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
   .dropna(how='all')
)`

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.loc[~df1.isna().all(axis=1)].fillna(method='ffill')\
    .groupby(['Name','place']).agg(','.join)\
    .pers_data.str.split(',',expand=True).add_prefix('other_')\
    .rename(columns={'other_0':'pers_data'}).reset_index()
        
                Name place        pers_data             other_1    other_2
        0  Smith John    NY  sjohn@gmail.com           0987 4567  0653 6734
        1   Vic Stied    SA        0986 5332  vickie@hotmail.com       None
```